# view.findViewById returns null for ImageView but not ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

When using `view.findViewById(id)` in my fragment to find the `ListView`, this returns fine and I can use the value, however, when I try to find the `ImageView` using the exact same method but just changing the ID to the correct one, it will return null, which causes problems later in the application.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_boardlist,
                container, false);

        boardListView = (ListView) fragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.fragmentListView);
        stickyImageView = (ImageView) fragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.favouriteImageView);

            // ...          

        return fragmentView;
    }
```

Not sure why this is happening as I am using the same way so I was wondering if anyone else knew why.

Here is the XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/initialsTextView"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight=".85"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/favouriteImageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight=".15"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_contentdescription"
    android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_off" />
```

Comment: Can you post the xml where the ImageView resides?

Comment: @E.Odebugg, sure. I have added it to the question.

Comment: Did you forget to copy the ListView portion of your XML file?

Comment: @dymmeh the `ListView` is in the fragment itself, this is the XML for a custom `ListView` row.

Comment: You're loading an entire fragment for a single list row? To get the ListView from a ListFragment just call getListView().

Comment: @dymmeh Not sure if I explained it well, the fragment contains the `ListView` item and then I load in and set data for each row through an adapter. In my fragment now I would like to get the `ImageView` as a variable so I can add a touch listener to it. The XML I posted above is the XML for each row in the `ListView`.

Comment: should the `ImageView` be declared in the fragment xml?

Comment: @chancea I'm kind of new to android but as far as I know I don't think so as the ImageView is meant to be on each custom row in the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but if you are trying to access an ImageView that is part of the custom row of the ListView, first you need to set the adapter. Then you need to override the getView() from the Adapter. Then get a reference of the ImageView.

Comment: Yes, the ImageView is a part of the custom row. I have the adapter set up with getView() working, the data will be filled correctly on the application but in my fragment I'm trying to set up a listener for the ImageView so the user can toggle the row as a favourite.

Comment: Ah, I just figured it out. I was trying to put the listener in the fragment which now I have thought over it, was stupid. I just need to set up the listener in the `getView()` method in the adapter. Thanks.